# amazon cloudfront: find all assets which are cached

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

I need to write a task to remove all assets from our cloudfront bucket when we deploy.

Currently, I do not track dynamically created assets (specifically our css files which are created via sass) in my version repository so it is impossible for me to say "diff this commit with that commit and give me all the css files that have changed b/c those are the files we need to invalidate".

Given this, I am thinking I just need to invalidate all assets of a given type, say css, whenever I deploy. However, I do not see how it is I can retrieve any/all assets cloudfront has cached.

Does anybody know how to ask cloudfront for all active assets which they have cached in my bucket? Or even better, all assets of a given type (css, js, png) that they have cached?